# What are LDAP usecases? is it still useful?

Tags: ldap

My question is: when should LDAP be used rather than DB? Is it still useful nowadays?

(please don't explain HOW TO set up LDAP server, I just wanna figure out, is LDAP still used on **new** projects, and what are the usecases when SQL/NoSQL DB are useless)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty broad question because you did not even mention which kind of applications are in scope.

Since quite some years applications support LDAP for accessing centralized enterprise IAM databases containing user and group information for access control. Especially there are standard schema definitions for this use-case. So still every application aiming to be attractive in such an environment should be capable of making use of it as a LDAP client.

Also each IAM system should still provide an LDAP service even if the underlying database is something else.

In theory one could of course use any other DB for this but there is no standardized access protocol and schema which makes multi-vendor integration very hard.

Comment: Thank you, please clarify do you mean clients to LDAP server by saying: _still every application aiming to be attractive in such an environment should be capable of making use of it_ ? How about create LDAP servers , is it sensible nowadays?

Comment: It does not make sense to implement new generic LDAP servers. But extending/integrating a LDAP server with IAM system makes sense. Anyway the question is a bit broad to give a complete answer.

Comment: I just wanna figure out is LDAP worth to study it and apply at enterprise or is it completely outdated thing still alive only due to support and maintenance duties. Nothing special i wanna figure out here

Comment: I think Ludo and me generally answered that. Without more context it's impossible to give a more detailed answer. Personally I would only study what's useful for my personal use-cases or for my customers' needs. You're the only one who knows what you need.

Answer (score 2):

The question is definitely too broad, and confusing.
LDAP is a protocol and a datamodel.

An LDAP Server (or LDAP Directory Server) is a specialised database that implements the protocol and services. Usually directory servers are optimised for reads and search, returning results in milliseconds. Somehow, LDAP Directory Servers were probably the first and [forgotten NoSQL databases](https://www.engineyard.com/blog/ldap-directories-the-forgotten-nosql).

Because LDAP is a standard protocol, it means that client applications do not need a driver specific to the server, but can interact with different vendors' products.

Other benefits of LDAP directory servers are access controls to the data, support for multi-master replication allowing high availability with geographically distributed data-centers, ability to search efficiently on almost any attribute of a record...

Today's modern LDAP directory servers, such as OpenDJ, can handle billions of objects, several hundred thousands of queries per seconds, and 5 nines availability.

Comment: Thank you. So what is the main reason when LDAP server should be set up rather than DB ? I mean provide, please, a usecase when definitely LDAP should be used

Comment: Central repository for the Identities in an Identity and Access Management solution, either for internal use (network infrastructure) or for external use (portals and online services). Banks, Telco operators, Insurance, Media, Gaming companies... all of them use LDAP Directory Services as the central place for storing user identities and credentials.

Comment: @arminvanbuuren Ask yourself this question: how do I authenticate my users against a SQL server? You can set this up, for sure, but you need to design everything from the ground up and it will be a unique solution. With LDAP, identification and authentication have been standardized.

Comment: I'm not familiar to SQL Server, I'm in Java/Spring, MySQL/PostgreSQL/Oracle. There are a lot of intensification possibilities like Spring Security/OAuth/JWT etc. That's exactly why I asked the question: when should I use LDAP rather than Spring Security/OAuth ? I appreciate a good usecase also... thanks in advance

Comment: OAuth is not an authentication protocol, it's an authorization protocol. One still needs to authenticate to obtain an OAuth access token. Identity and Access Management solutions are providing services that you can use to authenticate your users, and these solutions are usually leveraging LDAP directory servers. Or you can directly authenticate your users using LDAP, but it's more difficult to change later and introduce multi-factor or biometric authentication. As @mvreijn replied, if you need to do authentication against users stored in any SQL server, you're build your own unique solution.